# Listing issue, GROUP mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, twitter-bootstrap, pdo

Here is a mock-up example of `Mysql` table:

```
| ID  |  Country  |  City      |
________________________________

| 1   | Sweden    | Stockholm  |
| 2   | Sweden    | Stockholm  |
| 3   | Sweden    | Lund       |
| 4   | Sweden    | Lund       |
| 5   | Germany   | Berlin     |
| 6   | Germany   | Berlin     |
| 7   | Germany   | Hamburg    |
| 8   | Germany   | Hamburg    |
```

Notice how both rows `Country` and `city` have repeated values inside them.

Using `GROUP BY country, city` in my PDO query, the values will not repeat while in `loop`. Here is PDO for this:

```
$query = "SELECT id, city, country FROM table GROUP BY country, city";
$stmt = $db->query($query);
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :
```

The above code will result in an output like this (some editing in-between). `GROUP BY` works but the `country` repeats:

```
Sweden - Stockholm
Sweden - Lund
Germany - Berlin
Germany - Hamburg
```

Using bootstrap collapse and above code, I separate the `country` from the `city` with a simple drop down collopase. Here is code:

```
<li>
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?= $row['id']; ?>" 
href="search.php?country=<?= $row['country']; ?>">
<?= $row['country']; ?>
</a>

<div id ="<?= $row['id']; ?>" class="collapse in"> //collapse div here 
<a href="search.php?city=<?= $row['city']; ?>">
<?= $row['city']; ?><br></a>
</div> //end
</li>
```

It then looks something like this (once collapse is initiated):

```
Sweden 
> Stockholm
Sweden
> Lund
Germany
>Berlin 
Germany
>Hamburg
```

Here is where I face the problem. The above lists the values `Sweden` and `Germany` 2 times. I want `Sweden` and `Germany` to only list one time, and the cities listed below, so the desired look is to be this:

```
Sweden // Lists one time
> Stockholm
> Lund
Germany // Lists one time
>Berlin 
>Hamburg
```

I have tried using `DISTINCT, GROUP_CONTACT` and other methods, yet none get my desired output (above). Suggestions? Below is my current full code in action:

```
<?  
$query = "SELECT id, city, country FROM table GROUP BY country, city";
$stmt = $db->query($query);
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :

?>
<li>
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?= $row['id']; ?>" 
    href="search.php?country=<?= $row['country']; ?>">
    <?= $row['country']; ?>
    </a>

    <div id ="<?= $row['id']; ?>" class="collapse in"> //collapse div here 
    <a href="search.php?city=<?= $row['city']; ?>">
    <?= $row['city']; ?><br></a>
    </div> //end
    </li>       
        <?  endwhile ?>
```

Comment: That is propably because you are using `$row['id'];` as Id and it is not grouped in your query. and every id you have is diferent one from another one. You should use `<div id ="<?= $row['country']; ?>` instead.

Comment: Try using something to the affect of `$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT ".$id.", ".$city.", ".$country." FROM table GROUP BY country, city WHERE country = :id");` @SethCodes

Comment: @jorge `<?= $row['country']; ?>` still repeats.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Can you example this for me?

Comment: @SethCodes That would be the line of code to use, can you try it out and see? Just replace it with your existing `$query = "SELECT id, city, country FROM table GROUP BY country, city";` and `$stmt = $db->query($query);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Fetches nill.

Comment: Then try `$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT id, city, country FROM table GROUP BY country, city WHERE country = :id");` also replace the word `table` with your own table name, unless if your table name is called `table` then you will need to put it in backticks, since it's a reserved word. Or `WHERE country = :country");` @SethCodes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40083/discussion-between-sethcodes-and-fred-ii)

Comment: I still think that you dont have problem with your data result since you are getting countrys and cities, so, your collapse code should be the catch

Comment: @JorgeCampos Mysql is doing it's job, it's in listing, I can't seem to find a method to limit it's echo on every city record.

Comment: OOOh man.. I understand what is wrong. You have to have a variable that stores current country and check with the next country in the loop if it is the same you wont print the `<a` tag just the div for the citie

Comment: @SethCodes Just a quick note/question in wondering why you already have duplicate entries in your table. It's rather quite easy to implement a duplicate check before inserting into DB, which I suggest you use ASAP.

Comment: @fred -ii It's a mock example, the database has more columns, these duplicate entries hold addresses.

Answer (score 0):

So, as discussed your mysql result isn't the problem. you have some logic to change.
I don't have a enviroment to check, please let me know if it wont owrk.

```
$currCountry = "";
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :
?>
<li>
    <?if ( $currCountry != $row['country'] ) {?>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?= $row['id']; ?>" 
         href="search.php?country=<?= $row['country']; ?>">
         <?= $row['country']; ?>
         </a>
    <?
    }
    $currCountry = $row['country'];
    ?>

<div id ="<?= $row['id']; ?>" class="collapse in"> //collapse div here 
<a href="search.php?city=<?= $row['city']; ?>">
<?= $row['city']; ?><br></a>
</div> //end
</li>       
<?  endwhile ?>
```

Comment: Closer, however collapse breaks things. collapse lists wrong. Any more help would be great...

Comment: Any more help? I am really stuck here,

Comment: Sorry man it was very late yestarday here in my time zone. So try to change in my code that: `data-target="#<?= $row['id']; ?>"` on the `<a` tag for this: `data-target="#<?= $row['country']; ?>"` and on the div tag, this `<div id ="<?= $row['id']; ?>"` for this `<div id ="<?= $row['country']; ?>"` and give it a test

Comment: thanks for your time, really want to try and get to a solution with this one, but nothing seems to work... I tried above, but still face some error, maybe a complete alternative would be the way to go? Maybe load results via ajax in collapse?

Comment: Can you pastebin your generated html ?

Comment: Using this method: `SELECT id, country, group_concat(city) AS city, country FROM retailers GROUP BY country` has gotten me closer, the only issue with this is now my city links to generate correctly. Any soultions?