# group_concat issue, need unique

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am pulling data from MYSQL and using GROUP_CONCAT and AS.

```
<ul class="retailers-list">
<?  
$query = "SELECT id, country, group_concat(DISTINCT city SEPARATOR '<br>') AS city, country FROM retailers GROUP BY country";
$stmt = $db->query($query);
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :
?>
<li>
<a href="search.php?country=<?= $row['country']; ?>"><?= $row['country']; ?></a>
<br>
<a href="search.php?city=<?= $row['city']; ?>">
<?= $row['city']; ?></a> //group_concat / AS
</li>   
<?  endwhile ?>     
</ul>
```

The problem is that the output is one link. It seems to group all of the city values into $row['city'];. How Can I get each city to have it's own unique link, I need to use group_concat and AS and also give each city it's own unique URL.

Related post: [Listing issue, GROUP mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626632/listing-issue-group-mysql)

Comment: `SELECT id, country, city FROM retailers GROUP BY city` ... `<?= $row['city']; ?><br />`

Answer (score 1):

Here was my solution! Solved!

```
<ul class="retailers-list">
<?  
$query = "SELECT id, country, group_concat(DISTINCT city) AS city, country FROM retailers GROUP BY country";
$stmt = $db->query($query);
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :
?>
<li>
<a data-pjax="content" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?= $row['id']; ?>" href="retailers.php?country=<?= $row['country']; ?>">
<?= $row['country']; ?></a>


<div id ="<?= $row['id']; ?>" class="collapse in">
<?php 
  $cities = explode(',',$row['city']);
  foreach ($cities as $city) {
?>
    <a data-pjax="content" href="retailers.php?city=<?= $city ?>"><?= $city; ?></a><BR>
<?php
  }
?>
</div>
</li> 
<?  endwhile ?>
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's like a precious drug, 3 days I have stuck and then finally it works! The reason I love code is because of this feeling.

Comment: I know what you mean, I too spent the better part of 3 days last week or so, to also figure something out. It is a good feeling indeed when something has been solved/achieved.

Comment: There some issues with this solution. 1) GROUP_CONCAT has limits in the amount of results that can concatenate. You should check the docs 2) You're processing data unnecessarily as you are first imploding and then exploding, which makes no sense 3) You are mixing data with it's representation. EG: What would happen if a comma `,` is added to a value in the `city` field?

Comment: @SethCodes I do believe you can mark your own answer as accepted, in order to close the question, cheers.

Comment: @MostyMostacho Thanks for your tips! much appreciated. What would be your approach here? I have been through the docs but limited to the in-depths of it all.

Comment: I've just added an answer as it doesn't fit in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

In short you should go for the simplest query:

```
SELECT id, country, city FROM retailers GROUP BY country ORDER BY country
```

Note you didn't order the result by country and it seems it is a must based on your question.

Then you basically perform (what I think in English is called a) flow-control cut. That is, you will have results such as:

```
Country   | City
----------+-------------
Argentina | La Plata
Argentina | Buenos Aires
USA       | New York
USA       | Los Angeles
Brazil    | Sao Paulo
```

So you basically need 2 loops (one for each nesting level). One to distinguish the countries and one to output all the different cities for a country. In pseudo-php-code:

```
row = get_next_result
while (row) {           // while there are still elements to be fetched
  current_country = row[country]
  while (row && current_country == row[country]) {
    output current_country and row[city]
    row = get_next_result
  }
}
```

I leave the translation to PHP to you... but this is 99% of the work :P